# Access, Porque no funciona el after update?

Tags: ms-access-2010

Tengo una tabla con puestos de trabajo, y quería crear un macro after update, que al cambiar un campo, se introdujeran en la tabla de ceses el nombre, apellido y el id del puesto que se ha modificado. Esto es lo que tengo hecho, y no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: *Esto es lo que tengo hecho, y no funciona* Se necesita más información para poder dar una respuesta, así como datos de ejemplo y el output esperado. En cualquier caso, [el evento AfterUpdate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.form.afterupdate-event) se ejecuta una vez se hayan **salvado** los cambios en la tabla, no se ejecuta simplemente por cambiar un campo hasta que no se confirmen los cambios.